# Capybara unable to find the link of the object created by Factory_Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

A similar problem happened to me when I was doing an example problem. Capybara was not picking the text that was there. In this Capybara is not picking the link for the object that is there. Am I missing something?

Error message:

```
When I click the link "Why is earth round?"            # features/step_definitions/queston_steps.rb:6
      no link with title, id or text 'Why is earth round?' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      (eval):2:in `click_link'
      ./features/step_definitions/queston_steps.rb:7:in `/^I click the link "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/viewing_questions.feature:9:in `When I click the link "Why is earth round?"'
```

These are my test gems:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

These are my codes.

Scenario:

```
Scenario: Listing questions
Given I am on the home page
And there is a question "Why is earth round?"
When I click the link "Why is earth round?"
Then I should be on the page for "Why is earth round?"
And I should see "Question: Why is earth round?"
```

Factory definition:

```
Factory.define(:queston) do |q|
  q.question "Why is earth round?"
end
```

Step definition:

```
Given /^there is a question "([^"]*)"$/ do |question|
  FactoryGirl.create(:queston, :question => question)
  #Queston.create(:question => question)
end

When /^I click the link "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end
```

View:

```
<ul>
    <% @questons.each do |queston| %>
        <li><%= link_to queston.question, queston %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

*Queston* is the model class and *question* is its attribute.

Comment: Can you post the error that you receive when you try running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my scenario. I have to simply declare the object first, like this:

```
Scenario: Listing questions
Given there is a question "Why is earth round?"
And I am on the home page
```

Instead of

```
Scenario: Listing questions
Given I am on the home page
And there is a question "Why is earth round?"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a typo: your FactoryGirl factory defines a model called `queston`, not `question.`

If it isn't, I'd try raising the question and the response body to see what's being generated in each place. Obviously something isn't being generated correctly.

Comment: Yes, Queston is the model. Its not a typo.